# How do we bypass JWT Authorization for custom endpoints in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I am working on a custom endpoint for WP REST API, It looks like There is an issue with JWT Authentication for WP-API plugin, so when I request the API it is always giving me `"Authorization header malformed"` error in response.
something like this:

```
{
"code": "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header",
"message": "Authorization header malformed.",
"data": {
"status": 403
}
}
```

For my API I am using Basic auth with Wordpress Application password, this is getting interfered by JWT plugin. Is there a way I can avoid this only for my customs endpoints. I have been going through many solutions on the net nothing seems working.

This is how I have done the custom endpoint:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route(
    'myapi',
    'myendpoint',
        [
            'methods' => 'post',
            'callback' => 'my_api_callback',
            'permission_callback' => function () {
                    return current_user_can( 'administrator' );
                }           
        ]
    );
 });
```

In the "JWT Authentication for WP-API" plugin file - "jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api\public\class-jwt-auth-public.php" in the `public function determine_current_user( $user )` I have added a small condition check to bypass my API, that's how now this working for me. But I know this is not the right way. How can we bypass JWT  for custom endpoints? I believe this "determine_current_user" filter can do the trick, but I don't know how to override this, nothing worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hacky, but it looks like you can add "token/validate" to your request path or in a query string arument, and that will cause jwt bypass the token verification.  For me, I changed my request to https://local.com/wordpress/wp-json/v1/callback?path=token/validate

Comment: Thanks @zebfross, that's a good catch. But I wonder if is there any other way around to overcome this. I can see they are using the "determine_current_user" filter for this, can we have any option to add or override their filter? I have been playing around with this but so far no luck.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add/set a query string in the backend, I mean without asking the user to sent token/validate as a parameter can we set request params. I am not an expert in PHP, so just asking, I see something like this WP_REST_Request::set_param